# Get All Controller Names in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get all controller names  and `ActionNames` in my `MenuController` to show in `Dropdown`.

For Example

```
 ViewBag.ActionNames = GetActionNames();
 ViewBag.ControllerNames = GetControllerNames();
```

How do I get all controller names in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: You can use .Net Reflection to get all the controller names in your controller namespace, and also, action names

Comment: Try this
   public static List<string> GetControllerNames()
        {
            List<string> controllerNames = new List<string>();
            GetSubClasses<Controller>().ForEach(
                type => controllerNames.Add(type.Name));
            return controllerNames;
        }

        private static List<Type> GetSubClasses<T>()
        {
            return Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(
                type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(T))).ToList();
        }

sorry I am unable to post answer

Answer (score -1):

Call `ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action")`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: PO has asked to get **all** controller names.

Comment: But I need all Controller Names in the Project